# measure on sphere

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In a set of notes I am using (physics related), it states that "we denote $$M = \{ (x,y,z)| x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \}$$ and $L^2(M)$ the space of square integrable functions on $M$ with measure $$\Omega = (\theta, \phi),~~0 \leq \theta \leq \pi, ~0 \leq \phi \leq 2 \pi$$ and $$d \Omega = \sin \theta d \theta d \phi."$$ Is it clear how this defines a measure? As I know a [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) is defined as a function from a $\sigma-$algebra to the real line, which satisfies the properties as in the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here $M$ is parameterized via the map $\varphi:\Omega\to M$ defined by
$$\varphi(\theta,\phi)=\left(\begin{matrix}\sin\theta\cos\phi\\\sin\theta\sin\phi\\\cos\theta\end{matrix}\right).$$
When we say that $d\Omega=\sin\theta~d\theta~d\phi$ is a *measure*, we really mean that it is the "density" of a measure. That is, for a measurable set $U\subseteq\Omega$ (respect to the Borel or Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra) we have the measure of $U$ given by $d\Omega$ is 
$$\Omega(U):=\int_{U}d\Omega=\int_{U}\sin\theta~d\theta~d\phi=\int_{U}\sin\theta~d\mathcal{L}^2(\theta,\phi),$$
where $\mathcal{L}^2$ is the usual Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. This is all well defined since $\sin\theta$ is a measurable function with respect to $\mathcal{L}^2$. It shouldn't be hard to check that $\Omega$ defined this way is a measure.

Now if we have an integrable function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ and a measurable set $U\subseteq\Omega$ one can check that  $$\int_{U}f(\theta,\phi)~d\Omega=\int_{U}f(\theta,\phi)\sin\theta~d\theta~d\phi,$$
which in some sense justifies the notation $d\Omega$.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. So $\Omega$ it is a measure defined using the Lebesgue integral of $\sin \theta$. That's interesting.

Comment: Isn't it a bit confusing, possibly bad notation, that they use $\Omega$ to denote the set of ordered pairs $(\theta, \phi)$ and the measure $\Omega(U)$?

Comment: I completely missed that notational issue. Ya, I wouldn't call the measure $d\Omega$ since the domain is called $\Omega$, but rather something like $dA$ since it represents the infinitesimal area element on the sphere.